# Inserting Time in Different Time Zones in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am building a Google Sheet. In it, there is a column for a person's `Name`, his/her `Country` and their `Time Zone`. I want to add another column which shows the `Time` in their country in real time.

| Name | Country | Time Zone | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | Sri Lanka | GMT+5:30 | (Their real time should come here) |
| ABC | Abu Dhabi | GMT +4 | (Their real time) |

How do I get that? I tried to do `=NOW( )-(1.5/24)` which should ideally deduct 1.5 hours from my current time. But it doesn't work. (My time zone is GMT+5:30)

Comment: It is funny, but assume the value 1 is one day, we can do the following:
`TheirTime =  MyTime + 1 / 24 * 1.5`

This basically says, that TheirTime = MyTime + (One Day / 24 Hours * 1.5  Hours)

Comment: `I tried to do =NOW( )-(1.5/24) which should ideally deduct 1.5 hours from my current time. But it doesn't work.` I cannot reproduce this. When I do this, I get the expected time (1.5 hours deducted). Are you sure the spreadsheet's time zone is the one you think? Can you please provide more details about `it doesn't work`? Consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on, free of sensitive information.